# Select first node with concrete class with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I know how I can select the first node of XPath selection. 
I know how I can select the node with concrete in XPath selection.

```
//shipTo[@country='US']

//shipTo[1]
```

But how to connect it and get the first node with the concrete class ?

Answer (score 0):

How does `(//shipTo[@country='US'])[1]` work for you?

That would be the first node in the document with that class.

If you want all the first children with this class of some parent nodes, you could simply use `//shipTo[@country='US'][1]`

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. E.g. `//span[@class="vote-count-post "][1]` on this very page highlights both vote counts (with a chrome extension)

Comment: Please make sure to include the parenthesis as proposed by @paul. Without, you're querying the first matching shipTo element in _each_ parent node, with you're querying the first over all the document.